# Sqlachemy returning function not returning relationship content

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlachemy to interact with a postgres database. Let's say I have the following tables:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String)
    posts = relationship("Post", back_populates="author")


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    content = Column(String)
    author = relationship("User", back_populates="posts")
```

I want to be able to update a `Post` while returning it's content, including the author's content.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
query = update(Post).where(Post.id == 1).values(content="post content").returning(Post)
```

I was expecting to have the full Post data, including the `Author` field. In reality, only the fields specified in `Post` table are returned.
If you look closer to the generated query and print it, the following is shown

```
UPDATE posts SET content=:content WHERE posts.id = :id_1 RETURNING posts.id, posts.author_id, posts.content
```

As you can see, the `Author`'s fields and join instructions are not added to the query which is actually consistent with the result(of course).

I already looked into [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Update.returning) and didn't see any mention to returning relationships.

So, my question is: is there any way to update the database content while returning the updated entity and it's relations data?

Full code

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, update
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

# Define the SQLAlchemy model
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String)
    posts = relationship("Post", back_populates="author")


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    content = Column(String)
    author = relationship("User", back_populates="posts")


query = update(Post).where(Post.id == 1).values(content="post content").returning(Post)
print(query)
```

Comment: Don't do that.  What I mean is, give up the tendency to write overly clever one-liners.  `UPDATE` queries do not return anything, so you are trying to combine two unrelated operations here.  Just do them in two separate steps.

Comment: Can't you execute the query like `for post in session.execute(query).scalars(): print(post.author)` to get the relations? If not, can you explain what you expect?

Comment: @python_user I think the OP wants the update statement to return not only the Post instances but also the User instances without emitting any selects. Like having `.options(joinedload(Post.author))`, which curiously SQLA allows on the update statement, but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @TimRoberts even though you're right for my specific case, there might be a legit reason to do what I'm trying to do. For example, if you have a lot of database load and master/slave architect, you wanna do only one query to make it more performant and to make sure you get the up to date info.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's exactly what I want.

Comment: Maybe so, but when what you want to do violates limitations, you find a different way.  An efficient implementation that doesn't work isn't worth very much.